# Unhide an <asp:Panel> using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an `<asp:Panel>` that is hidden with css  `display: none;` and I'd like to show the panel when I have an error. Setting the style to `'block'` in the javascript isn't working.

```
document.getElementById('<%= UxErrorPanel.ClientID %>').style.display = 'block';
```

```
<asp:Panel CssClass="alert alert-danger hidden" ID="UxErrorPanel" runat="server">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="UxLabelErrorHeader" Text="Unable to connect to the Stripe payment provider"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="UxLabelErrorMessage"></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: any errors in your browser console? have you checked the rendered HTML and JS (using your browser's Inspect or View Source tool) to check if the IDs of the panel and the ID in the JavaScript match up? (The panel will be rendered as a `<div>`, so that's what you're looking for in the HTML.) Where does this JavaScript appear in your page? The way you've written it above, it will execute as soon as the script block is rendered in the browser. So if the script block is earlier than the panel in your page, it will execute before the panel exists, and therefore won't find anything to update.

Comment: Perhaps it's also due to the `hidden` class that's on the panel.  Try removing that class as well.

Comment: @ChrisBarr I was assume that was the class which was adding the `display:none` property. It certainly isn't added inline. But OP can use the element inspector to determine what rule is being applied, and where from. But yeah maybe it would make more sense to use JS to toggle that class, rather than setting the style property directly.

Comment: It's hard to know... I believe asp Panels will add inline styles to hide/show them and then any CSS classes added are done so manually.  We don't actually know anything about the CSS stylesheet here, so all we can do is guess.  IMO, if you want to hide/show a div only with JS, just use plain HTML instead of using server-side controls like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function HidePanel() {
            document.getElementById('<%= pnlMain.ClientID %>').style.display = 'block';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnPushMe" runat="server" OnClientClick="HidePanel(); return false;" Text="Push Me" />
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlMain" runat="server" style="display: none;">
                <label>Going to be hidden, soon.</label>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This was me just playing around.  But I think you can take this HTML/JS and get your own solution.

Edit: To add some more context with the change... I've had similar issues with CSS classes hiding an element via visibility attribute rather than display, which is why I set the `style="display: none;"` on the Panel. Note, IntelliSense might try to tell you this is not an attribute you can set, but just ignore that.  ASP controls can be a pain, sometimes.

If you're using jQuery, you can just use `.toggle()` or. `fadeToggle()` for some extra animations.

Comment: @TylerRoper Maybe you should read the initial question he asked.  He can't hide the Panel via JS.  I posted a solution for him.  It's not hard to comprehend.